# iterate over json in javascript

Tags: arrays, json

Want to iterate over this routes->bounds->legs->steps and alert(path). I am new to use json , can you please tell how to achieve this .thanks in advance.

JSON is --

```
    {"routes":[{"bounds":{"copyrights":"Map data ©2013 Google"},
"legs":["steps":[{"distance":{"text":"1 ft","value":0},
"path":[{"ib":39.049870000000006,"jb":-76.51013}],
"lat_lngs":[{"ib":39.049870000000006,"jb":-76.51013}],
"start_point":{"ib":39.04987000000001,"jb":-76.51013},
"end_point":{"ib":39.04987000000001,"jb":-76.51013}}],
"via_waypoint":[],"via_waypoints":[]}],"status":"OK"}
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't even valid. Have a look at this validator: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: i am getting json from google map api v3 for direction , i edit it to short it . so might miss some thing in that

Comment: @bux578 you please just tell the basic method to iterate over  routes->bounds->legs->steps  path and achieve "path" array.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to parse the JSON string you have received.
Then you're able to access all of it's properties via dot notation:

With jQuery you could do it like this:

```
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}


var json = '{"Name": "Apple","Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00","Price": 3.99,"Sizes": ["Small","Medium","Large"]}';

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);


$.each(obj.Sizes, function(index, item) {
   $("body").append("<p>" + item + "</p");
});
```

Look how I access the `Sizes` property on the parsed JSON string:
`obj.Sizes`